# VBA to save array of data to a given column of the spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a function in VBA that calculates the moving average, something like:

```
Function calculateMovingAverage(myDate As Date, myDateVector As Range, myPrices As Range, myWindow As Integer)

' use the series of prices to calculate the moving average over a number of days 
' i.e. if myWindow=50 then calculate the 50 days moving average

calculateMovingAverage = movingAvg

End Function
```

the function saves the results in an array having, let's say, 1000 elements. How can I make the code save this array from cell A1 to cell A1000?

Comment: Is the array populated within the `calculateMovingAverage` function or within a calling Sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via `.transpose`:

```
Range("A1:A1000").Value = Application.Transpose(movingAvg)
```

(Dynamically: `Range("A1:A" & UBound(movingAvg) + 1)...`)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ...

```
Range("A1:A1000").Value = movingAvg
```

I believe you can assign an array directly to a range of the correct size.

---

Failing that, you can loop through the values and add them individually ...

```
For i = 1 to 1000
    cells(i,1).Value = movingAvg(i)
Next i
```

Note you may have to play around with the value of i depending on wheteher you have `Option Base 0` or `Option Base 0` declared.

---

As Alex mentions, because the array is 1 dimensional, Excel may assume it should be output horizontally, rather than vertically, in which case, you would need to use `Transpose`. Thanks Alex :O)